# Not able to remove duplicate values and fetch values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a variable that prints the array in the following format. I wish to fetch the value of id but there should be no duplicate values. So according to the given array, the values of id that I want are

```
1,2,3,4
```

To get unique value i tried this code

```
array_unique($value, SORT_REGULAR);
```

and to fetch values i used this code

```
foreach( $value as $array => $pervalue) 
{
}
```

But still i am getting duplicate values and values of id are not getting fetched

Following is the array

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($value);
echo "</pre>";

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Flatten first, or use a recursive function, or loop an array_column call.  Array_unique alone will not do ...as you have discovered.  How are you building your input array?  Probably best to restructure while declaring  $value.  Please show us more code.  We can offer an "after the fact" solution, but restructuring earlier may be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, it is likely that the best approach would be restructuring your input array.  Until you provide your earlier code, we can only help after the array is generated.

Array_unique is great if you are not already handling each element.  Because you will need to traverse the array to isolate your id values, you may as well weed out the duplicates as you go.  Here are a few ways...

*note I am using temporary keys to avoid calling array_unique.  No duplicate values will be stored.

Code:  Demo: https://3v4l.org/BWT1R

```
$values = [
    [
        ["id" => 1],
        ["id" => 3],
        ["id" => 8]
    ],
    [
        ["id" => 1]
    ],
    [
        ["id" => 3],
        ["id" => 2]
    ]
];

$unique_ids = array_column(array_merge(...$values), "id", "id");
sort($unique_ids);
var_export($unique_ids);
echo "\n\n";

foreach ($values as $groups) {
    foreach ($groups as $rows) {
        $result[$rows["id"]] = $rows["id"];
    }
}
sort($result);
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 8,
)

array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 8,
)
```

And if you want to use recursion, here is a clean way:

```
array_walk_recursive($values, function ($v) use (&$result){
    $result[$v] = $v;
});
sort($result);
var_export($result);  // same output as above
```

Comment: Thank you for the recursive example.  I will remember that method!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $numbers = array(
        array(
            array(
                'id' => 1
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 3
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 4
            ),
        ),
        array(
            array(
                'id' => 1
            ),
        ),
        array(
            array(
                'id' => 3
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 2
            ),
        ),
    );

    $mag_numbers = array_merge($numbers[0], $numbers[1], $numbers[2]);
    $needed_result = array_column($mag_numbers, 'id');
    $final_needed_result = array_unique($needed_result, SORT_REGULAR);


    foreach( $final_needed_result as $single) 
    {
        var_dump($single);
    }
```

Comment: This method id only suitable if the number of subsets is 3. Only the OP will know if this is a suitable solution, but this is not a flexible solution.